# Finding Another Application Directory

Tags: vb.net, directory, registry

I'm writing an application that will add files to a number of another programs directories. I've been able to do this by asking the user to select the installation directory of the program, but I was hoping there would be a way to find the directory automatically. The complication I find is with multiple drives on some users PC's, I feel it would take too long to scan them all... Is there any method to find the directory of a program? Maybe the registry or something?

Comment: You will need to provide more details about what program(s) you are looking for.  One can write a program that has no registry entries or traces of its existence anywhere other than the directory where it's installed, so there's no "global" way other than scanning.

Comment: The programs are installed, they're games to be more precise. So they're properly installed in the file system & Registry.